# How to reload combobox items in one form from another form

Tags: c#

I have two window forms, Form1 is for country name and Form2 is for city name. In form2 I  have a comboBox which fetch country name from database that I saved by Form1 and its working fine and fetching data properly. But I want a button beside comboBox like 
[please see this image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MSqo.png),
and when click on it button will open Form1 and when I will add a new country in Form1, comboBox in Form2 should get updated and Form1 should close. How to do this? My code is...

In Form2 (for city name)

```
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add_Country ac = new Add_Country();
        ac.ShowDialog();
    }

public void refreshComboBox()
    {
        comboBox_CountryName.Refresh();
    }
```

In Form1(for country name)

```
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string country = txtBox_countryName.Text.ToLower();
        insertCountry(country);
        showCountry();
        Add_City ad = new Add_City(); //Form2 object refrence.
        ad.refreshComboBox();
        this.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Country added successfully.");
        clearControl();
     }
```

Comment: You could just call,your fill combo method on form closing event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `ac.ShowDialog()` helps you handle after the `Add_Country` form is closed. So, you can `refetch` the `countries` from `database` just after `ShowDialog` line such as;

```
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add_Country ac = new Add_Country();
    ac.ShowDialog();
    // Repopulate the Country Combobox 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in form2 after showdialog() refresh your combo,
you don't need to refresh it in the first form

```
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add_Country ac = new Add_Country();
    ac.ShowDialog();
    refreshComboBox()
}
```

when you are closing the dialog the run time cursor will be back to the form2 and the other story will be executed